# Rails avoid duplicated joins on scopes that have join and merge

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to refactor a model that has a lot of has_many :through associations that involve conditions on the join table

```
class Assignment
  has_many :assignment_reviewers
  has_many :preferred_assignment_reviewers, -> { preferred }
  # more of these for different types of reviewers

  has_many :reviewers, through: :assignment_reviewers
  has_many :preferred_reviewers, through: :preferred_assignment_reviewers
  # more of these
```

I added the following scope on Reviewer

```
class Reviewer
  scope :preferred, -> do
    joins(:assignment_reviewers).merge(AssignmentReviewer.preferred)
```

so that I could do

```
assignment.reviewers.preferred
```

instead of using the has_many

```
assignment.preferred_reviewers
```

However, the former results in a duplicate INNER JOIN

```
INNER JOIN `assignment_reviewers` `assignment_reviewers_reviewers`
ON `assignment_reviewers_reviewers`.`reviewer_id` = `reviewers`.`id`
INNER JOIN `assignment_reviewers`
ON `reviewers`.`id` = `assignment_reviewers`.`reviewer_id`
```

It seems I have three options:

1. Keep defining has_manys and has_many :throughs for each (downside: lots of specific associations on a model that is already a god class)
2. Use the scope (downside: duplicate join)
3. Use the merge directly

   ```
   assignment.reviewers.merge(AssignmentReviewer.preferred)
   ```

   (downside: not as eloquent)

I'm inclined to choose option 2 because cleaner code and I'm guessing the extra join won't have a substantial impact on performance.

Any advice / is there a better alternative that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution that I like better than the three I listed:

I added an extension block to my has_many :through declaration

```
has_many :reviewers, through: :assignment_reviewers do
  def preferred
    merge(AssignmentReviewer.preferred)
  end
end
```

While I will still have to declare a lot of extensions, this is a much more concise than declaring a has_many and has_many through for each has_many through that I need